# Hibernate search : NoSuchMethod org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionEnvironment.getJtaPlatform()?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I have a java project using spring and hibernate. I am integrating hibernate search to have a full text search. Since i've integrated hibernate search im a not able to save my entity. I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionEnvironment.getJtaPlatform()Lorg/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/spi/JtaPlatform;
```

The complete stacktrace is here http://pastebin.com/GTthsRv6

Here my spring controller when i want to save a project for a user:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/saveproject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveProject(@ModelAttribute Project  project,HttpSession session){
         User user = (User) session.getAttribute(USER);
         user.getProjects().add(project);
         ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
         modelAndView.setViewName("projectSuccess");
         modelAndView.addObject("project", project);
         userServices.updateUser(user);
         return modelAndView;
    }
```

Here the updateUser method implementation in services part:

```
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
@Service
public class UserServicesImpl implements UserServices {

@Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public void updateUser(User user) {
            userDao.updateUser(user);

        }
..other methods
}
```

Here is the update user method of @Repository:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl<User, Long> implements UserDao {

    protected UserDaoImpl() {
        super(User.class);
    }
    @Override
        public void updateUser(User user) {
            saveOrUpdate(user);

        }
...other methods
}
```

AbstractDaoImpl:

```
    public abstract class AbstractDaoImpl<E, I extends Serializable> implements AbstractDao<E,I> {

        private Class<E> entityClass;

        protected AbstractDaoImpl(Class<E> entityClass) {
            this.entityClass = entityClass;
        }

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public Session getCurrentSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }


        @Override
        public void saveOrUpdate(E e) {
            getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(e);
        }

    ... others methods


        public void indexDatabase(){
            Session session  = getCurrentSession();
            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);  
            try {
                fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

}
```

In my hibernate.cfg.xml i configure index :

filesystem
  E:\workspace\indexes

I use hibernate 4.2 and hibernate search 4.5. I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: This is about the versions of the artifacts. The class file does not contain the needed method, so it is very likely that you are using incompatible version of jar files.

Answer (score 5):

Wrong version of Hibernate ORM is used with Hibernate Search 4.5. Method `getJtaPlatform` exists, but return type differs.

In Hibernate 4.2 method TransactionEnvironment.getJtaPlatform() returns
[org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jta/platform/spi/JtaPlatform.html)

In Hibernate 4.3 it returns:
[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/spi/JtaPlatform.html)

Hibernate Search 4.5 needs Hibernate 4.3. This is documented for example [here](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/):

> You will need hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar and its transitive dependencies

Comment: Thanks Mikko for your reply. I've changed the hibernate version to 4.3.1.Final but i am getting another error.Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jta/platform/spi/JtaPlatform
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.<init>(SpringSessionContext.java:56)
 ... 139 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa. The complete error is here http://pastebin.com/YquUTN50. I think it's a spring and hibernate compatibility problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I used hibernate-search 4.5 Final in a maven project.
Maven imported the correct dependencies like hibernate-code 4.3 and so on but this problem still resists.
After ours of debugging and even going into the hibernate-core JAR, I gave up and tried **hibernate-search-orm 4.0 Final and hibernate-core 4.0 Final**. The Exception is gone and he found the missing methods.
Thats a very strange behaviour...
I know that's this isn't a clear solution but it works if you are able to live with the Version 4.0

Comment: This what i did but i am using hibernate-core 4.2.8.Final. It's also ok with this version. I hope it will be corrected soon. Thanks a lot

Comment: I was using Hibernate-core and Hibernate-search jars of different versions. I changed the version to 4.3.5.Final for both and the problem was solved.